# Object define property with class

Tags: javascript

Here I'm trying to explore more about object properties using Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor. But when I used the not-static method I'm getting nothing in response. I don't know what is the reason behind this.

**When I use getName method non-static**
output - undefined

```
class abc {
    getName() {
    return 'abc class name'
  }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(abc, 'getName'))
```

**When I use getName method static**
output - Object {writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}

```
class abc {
    static getName() {
    return 'abc class name'
  }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(abc, 'getName'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in your first scenario, `getName()` is an instance of method of objects that are of type `abc`:

```
let a = new abc();
a.getName() //'abc class name'
```

In your second scenario, using the `static` keyword you are creating a class method:

```
abc.getName() //'abc class name'
```

Only in the second scenario is `getName` set as an `ownProperty` for `abc`. In the first scenario, `getName` is available on the `prototype`.

Answer (score 1):

Cause non-static methods are part of the prototype:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(abc.prototype, 'getName')
```

As you know, class syntax is just syntactic sugar for:

```
function abc(){
  //the constructor goes here
}

abc.someStatic = 1;

abc.prototype = {
  getName(){
    //...
  }
};
```